# Python netcraft API or replacement library

Tags: python, header

I am looking to either interact with netcraft or pull similar data from the servers headers.

https://superuser.com/questions/120783/can-i-detect-what-webserver-a-website-is-using

Any pointers would be great all my googling shows how to make a python webserver which I don't need at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, assuming that the website is providing the server in the header tag, you could use python's [request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) framework to get the server header:

```
requests.get("website").headers["server"]
```

If you're not sure if the server will return the server, make sure it is checked before accessing the dict. Websites might also change the header values (especially the server header) dynamically. Many server also consider providing the server a security gap. So, don't expect every website to give you its server type. Servers might even hide it out of a sudden. A better example that prints the servers for multiple websites is:

```
import requests

def getServer(uri, default = "-- Server not given --"):
    request = requests.get(uri)
    if "server" in request.headers:
        return request.headers["server"]
    else:
        return default

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uris = [
        "http://superuser.com",
        "http://google.com",
        "http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/",
        "http://yahoo.com"
    ]

    for theURI in uris:
        print "Website: %s uses %s" % (theURI, getServer(theURI))
```

On my machine, as of July 7th, 2014 the script returns:

```
Website: http://superuser.com uses -- Server not given --
Website: http://google.com uses gws
Website: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ uses nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Website: http://yahoo.com uses ATS
```